# How to override operations, including the persistence process?

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com

I'm working with:

- Symfony 4.4 (lts)
- API Platform 2.5 (current version)

And I'm trying to override the delete operation so that the entity will not be always deleted, I must check if the entity has been used as foreign key with another entity so in this case, I don't delete I just set the flag property of my entity to `false`, if not, I delete the entity.

But the problem in the API Platform docs, overriding an operation is just modifying the entity before it will be persisted.

`src/Entity/Product`:

```
/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *     itemOperations={
 *         "get",
 *         "delete"={
 *             "controller"=ProductDeleteAction::class,
 *         }
 *     })
 */
class Product
{
    //...
}
```

`src/Controller/ProductDeleteAction`

```
class ProductDeleteAction
{
    private $manager;
    
    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $manager)
    {
       $this->manager= $manager;
    }

    public function __invoke(Product $product): Product
    {
         $categories = $this->manager->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository(Categorie::class)->findBy('product',$product);

         if(count($categories)){
             $product->setActive(false);
             return $product;
             //I want that the product been persisted But the product is deleted finallay because it's delete operation :(
         }else{
             return $product;
         }

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to use **Data Persisters**:

https://api-platform.com/docs/core/data-persisters/